# Porting regular expression from JavaScript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have a regular expression that runs on my JavaScript application.

`not.replace(/({[PF]}(.*?){\/[PF]})/g, '<a href="#projects/'+ project.get('slug') +'/' + project.get('uri_hash')+'">$2</a>');`

Basically it looks for {P} or {F} and {/P} or {/F} and turns the word between those characters in to a link, for example.

`{P}Haribo{/P}` would be output as `<a href="/link/link">Haribo</a>`. I want to move this functionality on to the server, but I am struggling to port in to a PHP version of the same expression. Does anyone have any idea how to write the PHP version?

Here is my attempt:

```
$string = $notification->notification;
$patterns = array(
    '/{P}/',
    '/{F}/',
    '/{\/F}/',
    '/{\/P}/',
);
$replacements = array(
    '<a href="#projects/'.$notification->relational_project->slug.'/'.$notification->relational_project->uri_hash.'">',
    '<a href="#projects/'.$notification->relational_project->slug.'/'.$notification->relational_project->uri_hash.'">',
    '</a>',
    '</a>',
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. All you are missing is the call to [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). If its first and second parameters are arrays, it'll replace member-by-member based on the pattern. So, your code then becomes:

```
$patterns = array(
  '/{P}/',
  '/{F}/',
  '/{\/F}/',
  '/{\/P}/',
);
$replacements = array(
  '<a href="#projects/'.$notification->relational_project->slug.'/'.$notification->relational_project->uri_hash.'">',
  '<a href="#projects/'.$notification->relational_project->slug.'/'.$notification->relational_project->uri_hash.'">',
  '</a>',
  '</a>',
);
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $yourText);
```

`$yourText` is a placeholder variable in the code. Replace it as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated code:

```
$re = '~{([PF])}(.*?){/\1}~'; 
$str = "{P}Haribo{/P}"; 
$slug = "link";
$urihash = "66";
$subst = '<a href="#projects/' . $slug . '/' . $urihash . '">$2</a>'; 
echo $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/qbQYmr)

Note that `{([PF])}(.*?){/\1}` matches `{`, then either `P` or `F` and puts into Group 1, then matches `}` and then 0 or more characters other than a newline up to a `{/` sequence followed by the text stored in capture group 1 (`\1` is a backreference), and then the closing `}`.

I assume there are no nested `[...]`s in your strings.

Comment: I hope this will work for you. Just replace `$slug` with `$notification->relational_project->slug` and `$urihash` with `$notification->relational_project->uri_hash`.